# Adding white space between two elements - Figma

Tags: white-space, figma

While working with figma I frequently needed to add white space between the two elements such that all elements below these two elements should also shift down.

To explain better I have created a picture where first layout has three rectangle spaced by 50px. (*see original Layout*)

Now when I add 50px more between red and blue rectangle, the space between blue and green rectangle won't retain and they will be stacked over one another. (*see Actual Layout*)

but what I wanted is upon adding space between red and blue rectangle the space between blue and green rectangle should be maintained which is 50px. (*see Expected Layout*)

[image]

I wanted to know is it possible and how otherwise I have to select multiple elements and shift them manually whenever I want to add space between two intermediate elements.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can't you just group the blue and green rectangles, then move the group down by 50px?

Comment: Yes I can. the above picture meant for demonstration only. In real scenario I may have multiple elements below blue rectangle and I want all of them to push down instead of grouping them together. Microsoft onenote has a tool for this called `Insert or Remove Extra Space`.

Comment: If you don't want to group them, make a multiple selection of the objects you want to move, and then move down the entire selection.  I'm not a Figma user, but in most vector based applications, you can make a mutliple selelction by holding down Shift or Ctrl as you click.

Comment: yes @BillyKerr that's what I do. but I was looking for more flexible way of doing it. I did fair amount of google but nothing found. hope someone can assure me about it

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature to set a fixed space between objects, at least you are using an auto layout and that **won't fix your problem** where you want to move specific amount for every object. Auto layout is meant to create things such buttons, galleries, menus…

The most common way of doing this is just to create **frames**. If you have to move down a group of elements, frame them selecting them and <kbd>⌥ Option ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for Mac, or Windows equivalent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.